# Customization of HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want to get Like below image So I am working with **HorizontalScrollView** to get Carousel affects. I tried with [Coverflow Library](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/). But it use Gallery that is deprecated in API 16.

[image: Desired Result]

I achieved like follow & faced problem like:

- when run the program, all images is not shows small in size. After touching, it appears the real size what i set in code 300*300.
- Can't set the desired position of text view & Image View.

[image]

I used class **CenteringHorizontalScrollView**

```
public class CenteringHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView
    implements View.OnTouchListener {

private Context mContext;
private static final int SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR = 10;
private int mActiveItem;
private float mPrevScrollX;
private boolean mStart;
private int mItemWidth;

View targetLeft, targetRight;
ImageView leftImage, rightImage;
RelativeLayout leftFrame, rightFrame;

public CenteringHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mContext = context;
    mItemWidth = 100; // or whatever your item width is.
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getRawX();

    boolean handled = false;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mStart) {
            mPrevScrollX = x;
            mStart = false;
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mStart = true;
        int minFactor = mItemWidth / SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

        if ((mPrevScrollX - (float) x) > minFactor) {
            if (mActiveItem < getMaxItemCount() - 1) {
                mActiveItem = mActiveItem + 1;
            }
        } else if (((float) x - mPrevScrollX) > minFactor) {
            if (mActiveItem > 0) {
                mActiveItem = mActiveItem - 1;
            }
        }

        scrollToActiveItem();

        handled = true;
        break;
    }

    return handled;
}

private int getMaxItemCount() {
    return ((LinearLayout) getChildAt(0)).getChildCount();
}

private LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
    return (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
}

/**
 * Centers the current view the best it can.
 */
public void centerCurrentItem() {
    if (getMaxItemCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    int currentX = getScrollX();
    View targetChild;
    int currentChild = -1;

    do {
        currentChild++;
        targetChild = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(currentChild);
    } while (currentChild < getMaxItemCount()
            && targetChild.getLeft() < currentX);

    if (mActiveItem != currentChild) {
        mActiveItem = currentChild;
        scrollToActiveItem();
    }
}

private void scrollToActiveItem() {
    int maxItemCount = getMaxItemCount();
    if (maxItemCount == 0) {
        return;
    }

    int targetItem = Math.min(maxItemCount - 1, mActiveItem);
    targetItem = Math.max(0, targetItem);

    mActiveItem = targetItem;

    // Scroll so that the target child is centered
    View targetView = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem);

    RelativeLayout centerFrame = (RelativeLayout) targetView;

    ImageView centerImage = (ImageView) centerFrame.getChildAt(0);
    TextView centerTextView = (TextView) centerFrame.getChildAt(1);

    int height = 300;// set size of centered image
    int widths = 300;
    // LinearLayout.LayoutParams flparams = new
    // LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, height);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            widths, height);
    centerImage.setLayoutParams(flparams);
    centerTextView.setLayoutParams(flparams);

    flparams.setMargins(50, 30, 50, 0);

    // get the image to left of the centered image
    if ((targetItem - 1) >= 0) {
        targetLeft = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem - 1);
        leftFrame = (RelativeLayout) targetLeft;
        leftImage = (ImageView) leftFrame.getChildAt(0);
        int width = 250;// set the size of left image

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                width, width);
        leftParams.setMargins(50, 30, 50, 0);
        leftImage.setLayoutParams(leftParams);
    }

    // get the image to right of the centered image
    if ((targetItem + 1) < maxItemCount) {
        targetRight = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem + 1);
        rightFrame = (RelativeLayout) targetRight;
        rightImage = (ImageView) rightFrame.getChildAt(0);
        int width = 250;// set the size of right image

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                width, width);
        rightParams.setMargins(50, 30, 50, 0);
        rightImage.setLayoutParams(rightParams);
    }

    int targetLeft = targetView.getLeft();
    int childWidth = targetView.getRight() - targetLeft;

    int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int targetScroll = targetLeft - ((width - childWidth) / 2);

    super.smoothScrollTo(targetScroll, 0);
}

/**
 * Sets the current item and centers it.
 * 
 * @param currentItem
 *            The new current item.
 */
public void setCurrentItemAndCenter(int currentItem) {
    mActiveItem = currentItem;
    scrollToActiveItem();
}
```

}
My **TestHorizontalScrollViewActivity** looks like:

```
public class TestHorizontalScrollViewActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout imageGallery;

Integer[] pics = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.android__logo_froyo,
        R.drawable.android_eclair_logo, R.drawable.android_ics_logo,
        R.drawable.android_jellybean_logo,
        R.drawable.android_gingerbread_logo,

};

String[] texts = { "Hello", "Hi", "Welcome", "World", "Man", "Wan" };
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scrollview);
    imageGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearImage);

    for (int i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        RelativeLayout imageFrame = new RelativeLayout(
                TestHorizontalScrollViewActivity.this);
        TextView titleText = new TextView(
                TestHorizontalScrollViewActivity.this);
        titleText.setText(texts[i]);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(
                TestHorizontalScrollViewActivity.this);
        image.setBackgroundResource(pics[i]);
        // here you must set the layout properties of both textView and
        // imageView for getting the textView above imageView (I have no
        // time to do it now, may be, will edit code some other day)

        imageFrame.addView(image);
        imageFrame.addView(titleText);

        imageGallery.addView(imageFrame);
    }
}
```

}

& **activity_horizontal_scrollview.xml** looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.codencoder.ui.CenteringHorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/HSVImage"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearImage"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.codencoder.ui.CenteringHorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How I achieve this affects?